# SQL / .net Remoting and Security options/practices using them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, encryption, remoting

I am building a multi-tier application that will have multiple smaller apps apart from the main app to achieve certain goals.

Example:

I have a login class on my main app, asking for username and password. This class then does all the work, and then returns the login, with credentials, if any, or failed login state.

I want to re-use this code in my smaller client side app. Its precisely the same code, and outcome as in the main app. Therefore I want to re-use it, multiple times if necessary.

First Concern: If I use .net remoting, what security is applied? Would I have to encrypt my username and password initially, then send it through the remoting framework, and on the other side, decrypt it. And then back to the client again? I am worried about something sniffing out my username and password, and even if encrypted, can some clever hacker not just call my remote DLL with the encrypted "sniffed" credentials, as my remote DLL is expecting the encrypted format?

I am essentially trying to not make any DB connections from my smaller client app. Am I better off just putting the code in a local DLL (to the client app) and update the client app when my main DLL changes. If so, what security does MS SQL provide me for transmitting a SQL query containing the username and password to my remote SQL server?

I would appreciate any and all ideas regarding best practices and industry standards. I have always developed for an application server or desktop, so I never had to consider the security issues when sending data remotely.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since determined that remote access to a DB is just plain too slow to be usable. I am restucturing my solution to include a tcp middle teir, that sits next to the local db. This way I can have my business lgoic in the middle teir, and send appropriate updates to my conencted client.